# Inline date picker not working using jquery/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery to create an inline date picker but the entire `date picker` is only displayed. It does not even change months. I want it to display the date when calendar day is clicked.

The datepicker should display the date when clicked but no changes are shown in the `input` field. I searched for the same on stackover but no luck.

```
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" 
  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-
   awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
  <script 
  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-
  ui.min.js"></script>
   <a href="blog/2015/08/jquery-bootstrap-icons.download.html" data-icon="download-alt"></a>

              <div>
                <div class="ids" id="1" style="float:left; clear:both">
                  <b style="color: #444444">Date</b>
                  <input id="enterdate" class="duedatetextbox" data-inline = "true" type="text" placeholder="Enter date" tabindex="101" disabled>
                  <div id= "setdate" style = "margin-left:0px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ids" id="2" style="float:left;">
                  <b style="color: #444444">Time</b>
                  <input class="duedatetextbox" type="text" placeholder="Enter time" tabindex="102">
                </div>
              </div>
```

Jquery:

```
   <script type ="text/javascript">
    //date picker
  $('#setdate').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    altField: '#d'
   });

$('#enterdate').change(function(){
$('#setdate').datepicker('setDate', $(this).val());
  });
function adddescription()
 {   
$(`.description`).show();
$('.cardgutterrow').hide();
  }
</script>
```

CSS

```
div.ids {
    width: 50%;
 }

div.ids b {
    display: block;
}

div.ids input {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    background: whitesmoke;
    border: solid 1px grey;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ruju/q1fwaevL/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#setdate').datepicker({
 inline: true,
 altField: '#d',
 onSelect: onDateChange
});
function onDateChange(dateText, inst)
{
 $("#enterdate").val(dateText);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <div class="ids" id="1" style="float:left; clear:both">
  <b style="color: #444444">Date</b>
  <input id="enterdate" class="duedatetextbox" data-inline = "true" type="text" placeholder="Enter date" tabindex="101" disabled>
  <div id= "setdate" style = "margin-left:0px;">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="ids" id="2" style="float:left;">
  <b style="color: #444444">Time</b>
  <input class="duedatetextbox" type="text" placeholder="Enter time" tabindex="102">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! it works in fiddle. But it doesnt work on browser. What could be the reason?

Comment: what is the problem you got in browser?

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the date-picker correctly. I have removed some extra piece of code and added jquery-ui.min.css for proper styling of calendar

HTML-

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Script-

```
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

Updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/q1fwaevL/2/

You can refer api docs of jquery calendar here for other datepicker events- http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: But this is not inline `date picker`. The `date picker` is a coming as a popover.